# How to check date format c#

Tags: c#, .net, date-format

I have a c# block of code here:

```
    string inputString = textBox1.Text;
    DateTime dt;
    try
    {
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(inputString, "yyyyMMdd", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt) == true)
        {
            dt = dt.AddMonths(6);
            textBox2.Text = dt.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
        }
        else if (DateTime.TryParseExact(inputString, "yyyy.MM.dd", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt) == true)
        {
            dt = dt.AddMonths(6);
            textBox2.Text = dt.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
        }
    }   
    catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
```

Basically, what it does is, user input a string in textbox1, on button click, C# will check what date format is in the textbox, then add 6 months on the date and output it in the textbox2 to string format yyyyMMdd. As you see as of now, it accepts  yyyyMMdd and yyyy.MM.dd and do the same process. But my problem is I still got a lot of date format left:

```
dd-MM-yy 
yyyy/mm/dd 
yyyy-mm-dd 
yy/mm/dd
```

I don't want to use OR in my IF statement. Is there a way like WHATEVER the format is, will be accepted and do the process.
Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Your problem will be one of ambiguity. What should the following be interpreted as : 12/11/13. Is that 12 Nov or Dec 11?

Comment: 13 Nov 2012. The specific list provided are all actually unambiguous due to variations in punctuation and two/four digit years, though that's assuming that the list provided is the full list of all the formats they plan to use.

Comment: Oh!I see. So maybe I should stick to If else then?

Comment: I think that is all the date format they're planning to use...

Comment: I believe you can just say textBox2.Text = DateTime.Parse(inputString).ToString("yyyyMMdd"); Link to fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uuFZ1X

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[One of the](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx) [overloads of TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) accepts as its second parameter an array of strings. It won't tell you exactly which format was used, however. If you really do need that information, then yes, you're just going to have to run the one-format TryParseExact with each format you want, and see which one works.

And, of course, you'll need to make sure that all the formats you allow are unambiguous as to which parts are day, month, and year, or else you might parse 01/02/03 as any of six possible dates.

Comment: Hah, beat me by 30 seconds. :)

Comment: I am getting System.DateTime does not contain a definition for TryParse. I already have .globalzation on my namespace..

Answer (score 3):

[DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx) has an overload that accepts multiple formats to try parsing.

```
DateTime date;
DateTime.TryParseExact("11-Nov-13", new[] { "yyyy-MM-dd","MM/dd/yy","dd-MMM-yy"}, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out date);
```

However the comment from Lee Taylor is still correct in that if you have formats that can be ambiguous, you will not know exactly what's wrong.

If your solution requires that you return a formatted string using the same style as provided - then you'll need to pass your formats into a loop and try individually.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for all possible formats via using **CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns()** which is present under the namespace System.Globalization.

You can use **DateTime.TryParseExact** which has an overload  that accepts multiple formats to try parsing -
ParseExact(string s, string[] formats, IFormatProvider provider, DateTimeStyles style)

Example Code :

```
private DateTime GetDate(string date)
{
    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
    string[] formats = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns();

    try
    {
        dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(date, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
    }
    catch
    {
        throw ...;
    }

    return dateTime;
}
```